# Remover dados de dentro de um String

Tags: java, html, string, replace

No java eu estou lendo várias linhas de um arquivo HTML e nele eu tenho que retirar alguns dados e armazenar em variáveis. E para retirar esses dados eu tenho que remover algumas tags e dados que estão dentro de certos padrões.

Por exemplo, para remover as tags utilizo o `replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");`, mas agora preciso remover da *String* tudo o que está dentro de parênteses. Tentei utilizar o código `replaceAll("\\(.*?)", "");`, porém não deu muito certo.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que "escapar" o parêntese, caso contrário é considerado um grupo:

```
"Texto qualquer (texto)".replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "")
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo foi adaptado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256509/4551469) e encontra os textos entre parênteses (incluindo os parênteses:

```
String str = "Teste (Java)";
String parenteses = str.substring(str.indexOf("("), str.indexOf(")") + 1);
```

Se você precisa remover todo o texto da string (inclusive os parênteses), pode criar um *loop*:

```
String str = "Teste (Java)";

while (str.indexOf("(") >= 0 && str.indexOf(")") >= 0) {
    String parenteses = str.substring(str.indexOf("("), str.indexOf(")") + 1);
    str = str.replaceAll(parenteses);
}
```